# Non-Americans standing-up for Net-Neutrality at FCC's site?

Tags: support

I see your campaign asking users to leave comments about being in favor of Net Neutrality with the FCC.  I too am very in favor of Net Neutrality, but I'm not an American citizen nor do I live in the USA (I'm from Europe).

Since whatever the USA decides will impact the whole Internet - either by encouraging other countries (and the EU) to adopt similar laws allowing preferential treatment, or from services that will struggle (or never achieve greatness) under a new system - this proposal also concerns me.

However, do the FCC allow - not mention want - comments from non-Americans, or are only Americans allowed to leave comments with FCC?

Comment: Seems like this banner should be geo-targeted.  The site in the blog post seems to be practically US-only, given that it contacts representatives and members of Congress.

Comment: I would assume they're only interested in US Citizen comments. I do also believe they ask if you live in the US btw.

Comment: There might be an answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297816/net-neutrality-and-stack-overflow-stack-exchange There's a ton of answers now and I think a few of them discuss what non-US folks can/can't do.

Comment: If you go to the FCC's site, it does allow you to enter an international address, which *implies* it allows comments from non-US people. https://www.fcc.gov/ecfs/filings/express Proceeding: 17-108.

Comment: @BSMP well to be fair there are US citizens that live outside of the country so it could be to allow for them to comment not to allow anyone in the world to comment.

Comment: @JoeW I tried to find any clarification on that point but couldn't. The weird thing to me is that it doesn't appear to actually check that the person submitting the comment is American at all, unless there's a SSN check on the review page.

Comment: @Makoto on geo-targeted:  Perhaps - Perhaps not...  This do after all concern *all* users of the Internet - directly or indirectly.   Any information - like the blog post - is certainly appreciated to raise awareness, also outside the USA...  But perhaps it could mention that non-US citizens will have to find other ways to support Net Neutrality, since the FCC (seems to) only want input from Americans?

Comment: @BSMP On checking if poster is American:  And that really is a thing that concerns me - not only on the FCC-site, but also with other online petitions...  If I and other non-Americans leave our names, do we risk undermining the petition - allowing US politicians and authorities to dismiss the petition as mostly whining from foreigners?   But then again, what the US does impacts the rest of the world - especially regarding the Internet; so non-Americans *do* have an opinion on it.

Comment: May I suggest moving this discussion to the [SE meta post about this subject](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297816/net-neutrality-and-stack-overflow-stack-exchange)? This is off-topic here.